# Which folder to be used for user downloads in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I want to allow users save/download the images they see in my fast food app.

1) Which Folder should it save/download to?

2) Do I have to follow any extra steps so that they appear in photo gallery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `KnownFolders.SavedPictures` for more info check: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.knownfolders.savedpictures